# Art-style for a kids based game

Tags: style, style-identification, games

I'm working on a game project which is based on a Kids daily activities and games.
It needs obviously some cute graphics for which kids get interested in.

Since I'm working on a low-budget, I need a very cost effective yet a beautiful solution for art-style. I cannot allow my budget to have art style exploration as it is a time taking task.

I'm doing this exploration myself with references from other games and over internet.

Does anyone know a very good place where I can find abstracts of various art styles ?
I'm novice at art :(

If you have any good suggestion for my needs, please do post here.

Comment: Have you googled 'illustration styles'?

Comment: I did Google. But, may be because of my poor artistic thinking, I could not see many promising results for my needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mention a cost-effective solution for art style, I'd look into vector bundles or creation kits such as [this one](http://graphicriver.net/item/character-monster-creation-kit/5045134).

Some of them are even specifically aimed for games, like [this one](http://graphicriver.net/item/super-cat-game-assets/5966693). Lots of them are [characters](http://graphicriver.net/collections/3257771-characters-mascots), and they can be used for any app or even for digital books.

Of course you would only be able to use these if you want to create the apps yourself or you are comfortable enough with preparing the graphics for a dev. If that's not the case, then hiring someone to be in charge of the art is probably the best idea.